# MySQL Как узнать номер строки в скрипте при ошибке выполнения?

Tags: c#

Выполняю громадный скрипт, который выдает ошибку!
Код:

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
MySqlScript ScriptExecute = new MySqlScript(myConnection, script);
   try
   {
       ScriptExecute.Execute();
       DoScriptsResult = "GOOD";
   }
   catch (MySqlException ex)
   {
       // ex.Number - это НЕ номер строки, а номер исключения. а нужен номер строки...
       // ex.Message - это сообщение ошибки.
       DoScriptsResult = "ERROR";
   }
```

А мне нужно вывести номер строки в скрипте который выдает ошибку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
bool errorHappened = false;
int errorLine = -1;
MySqlScriptErrorEventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        errorHappened = true;
        errorLine = args.Line;
    };
try
{
    ScriptExecute.Error += handler;
    ScriptExecute.Execute();
    DoScriptsResult = "GOOD";
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    DoScriptsResult = "ERROR";
}
finally
{
    ScriptExecute.Error -= handler;
}
if (errorHappened) ...
```

Comment: Так вообще ошибка не появляется  (DoScriptsResult = "GOOD" всегда)

ScriptExecute.Error += handler; строчка мешает.

Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Что значит «мешает»? А в обработчик управление приходит?

Comment: В исключение не попадает catch (MySqlException ex),
даже если в скрипте ошибка.
Если строчку комментировать ScriptExecute.Error += handler; то попадает.

Comment: DoScriptsResult ВСЕГДА = "GOOD";

Comment: Давайте я всё же повторю вопрос: приходит ли управление в handler?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript.html
Взял код и та же проблема, скрипт не менял а ошибок не выдает...

Comment: Ну, поставьте breakpoint на `errorHappened = true;`, например.

Comment: Да, переходит. и errorLine = 0 возвращает.

Comment: Но весь блок не выполняется catch (MySqlException ex) {...}

Comment: Вот и отлично. Вот в этом handler'е и запоминайте, что случилась ошибка. А не в catch-блоке.

Comment: dbForge Studio при выполнении данного "поломанного" выдает: "Ошибка: (5,1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`,`assistant_id`) select `id`,`createDatetime`,`createPerson_id`,
`modifyDateti' at line 4"

Comment: 5я строка первый символ.

Comment: args.Exception.ToString() добавил в handler, но номер строки не тот(

Answer (score 0):

Переделал все, но данные по линии не получаю (постоянно 0). 
Полный код:

```
private void doScripts(string[] scripts, string server, string @base, string login, string paswd)
    {
        if (scripts == new string[] { })
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберете скрипт для выполнения!");
            return;
        }

        Connect = "default command timeout=0 ; Database=" + @base + "; Data Source=" + server + "; User Id=" + login + "; Password=" + paswd + "; charset=utf8";
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);

        if (this.OpenConnection(myConnection) == true) // Проверка коннекта
        {
            foreach (var item in scripts)
            {
                // Выполняем скрипт -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(myConnection, EncodingUTF8orANSI(item));
                bool errorHappened = false;
                bool errorIgnore = false;
                int errorPosition = 0;
                //string errorStatement = "";
                string errorStatementText = "";
                int errorLine = -1;
                int count = 0;
                MySqlScriptErrorEventHandler handler = (sender1, args) =>
                {
                    errorHappened = true;
                    errorLine = args.Line;
                    errorIgnore = args.Ignore;
                    errorPosition = args.Position;
                    //errorStatement = args.Statement;
                    errorStatementText = args.StatementText;

                    richTextBox1.AppendText("\n errorPosition: " + errorPosition +  // 0
                                            "\n errorStatementText: " + errorStatementText + // ""
                                            "\n Line:  " + errorLine + // 0
                                            "\n count: " + count + // 0
                                            "\n ERROR: " + args.Exception.Message + // выдает ошибку выполнения, как и положено
                                            "\n args.Position: " + args.Position); // выдает ошибку выполнения, как и положено
                    DoScriptsResult = "ERROR";
                };

                try
                {
                    script.Error += handler;
                    //script.Error += new MySqlScriptErrorEventHandler(script_Error);
                    script.ScriptCompleted += new EventHandler(script_ScriptCompleted);
                    script.StatementExecuted += new MySqlStatementExecutedEventHandler(script_StatementExecuted);

                    count = script.Execute();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    DoScriptsResult = "ERROR";
                }
                finally
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("\n finally");
                }
                if (errorHappened)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("\n ERROR");
                }
    private void script_Error(Object sender, MySqlScriptErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n args.Ignore: " + args.Ignore +  // 0
                                "\n args.Position: " + args.Position + // ""
                                "\n args.StatementText:  " + args.StatementText + // 0
                                "\n args.Line: " + args.Line + // 0
                                "\n ERROR: " + args.Exception.Message); // выдает ошибку выполнения, как и положено
    }

    private void script_StatementExecuted(object sender, MySqlScriptEventArgs args)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n script_StatementExecuted"); 
    }

    private void script_ScriptCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n script_ScriptCompleted");
        /// EventArgs e will be EventArgs.Empty for this method 
    }
```

В ответ получаю:

```
 script_StatementExecuted
 script_StatementExecuted
 args.Ignore: False
 args.Position: 0
 args.StatementText:  
 args.Line: 0
 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`,`assistant_id`) select `id`,`createDatetime`,`createPerson_id`,
`modifyDatetim' at line 4
 script_ScriptCompleted
 finally
```

Вот скрипт:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
set sql_safe_updates = 0;


insert into Visit (`id`,`createDatetime`,`createPerson_id`,
`modifyDatetime`,`modifyPerson_id`,`deleted`,`event_id`,`scene_id`,
`date`,`visitType_id`,`person_id`,`isPrimary`,`finance_id`,`service_id`,
payStatus`,`assistant_id`) select `id`,`createDatetime`,`createPerson_id`,
`modifyDatetime`,`modifyPerson_id`,`deleted`,`event_id`,`scene_id`,`date`,
`visitType_id`,`person_id`,`isPrimary`,`finance_id`,`service_id`,`payStatus`,
`assistant_id` from base2.Visit;

set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Необходимо получить 5ю строчку, в ней ошибка в запросе. (кавычки нет в 8й строке)